# Getting frame like boarder to the paragraph when click on it.only for Export CrystalReport to Worddocument

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

when I am trying to export `crystalreport` in to `worddocument` and then i have clicked on the paragraph and it shows frame like boarder to the paragraph.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report export each text object as text box in word so it will always insert multiple text boxes for each Para or text. If you want running text with settings then you have to write code to generate this word file.